# Biggest projects using Git?

Tags: git, dvcs

What are some of the biggest projects using git as a dvcs? Open source or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git was originally developed specifically to be used for managing the Linux kernel.

A list of other big projects  using git is available at the Git SCM Wiki: [Projects that use Git for their source code management](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitProjects)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean big as in popularity or big as in code size?

Here is a list of the most watched projects on [GitHub](https://github.com/popular/watched)

Don't forget that git itself uses git for version control.